# How add Contact Form in Magento CMS Page/Block

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, wordpress, contact-form

I use fishpig wordpress integration with addons contact form 7

documentation say this

To do this, you can make use of the Widget block (code below).

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="wp_addon_cf7/widget" name="cf7.test.form">
        <action method="setFormId"><form_id>4</form_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

To use the above code, simply change the number 4 for the ID of your form.

To display a form using PHP instead of XML, see the code below.

```
<?php $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout') ?>
<?php $formBlock = $layout->createBlock('wp_addon_cf7/widget') ?>
<?php $formBlock->setFormId(4) ?>
<?php echo $formBlock->toHtml() ?>
```

did anyone succeed us?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your cms page:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```